# Showing background image for OpenGL live wallpaper

Tags: java, android, mobile, opengl-es

I'm making an Android live wallpaper using OpenGL.

I would like to let the user pick an image to use for the background. Can someone give me any advice on an easy way to do this?

I know that I need to down sample bitmaps before loading them to avoid using huge amounts of memory for large bitmaps.

I also know OpenGL only supports texture sizes that are powers of two. It looks like messy work having to calculate the down scale factor then calculate the closest good texture size and then scale a quad with that texture appropriately to the screen.

It would also be nice to have the wallpaper panning feature when homescreens change.

Is there any easier way than doing all of the above myself? If not, is there sample code available for what appears to be a very common task?

Comment: If you insist on using OpenGL, you'll have to live with its limitations. Resource reloading upon context loss is another hassle that you'll have to deal with. Do you really have to use OpenGL in the first place, or would Canvas also work for you?

Comment: Canvas rendering is too CPU intensive for fancy effects (I've benchmarked it for my wallpaper), especially if you want any 3D effects. Giving this, do you have any tips?